# LWJGL Java - Lines/quads won't disappear when using the mouse co-ordinates

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm using the LWJGL in Eclipse and I have this code that I made:

```
public class test {
    public test() {
        int wx = 600;
        int hy = 450;

        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(wx, hy));
            Display.create();
            Display.setTitle("Hello World!");
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // init openGL
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, wx, hy, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            // render openGL
            int mouseX = Mouse.getX();
            int mouseY = Mouse.getY();

            while (Mouse.next()) {
                if (Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) {
                    System.out.println("(" + mouseX + ", " + mouseY + ")");
                }
            }

            while (Keyboard.next()) {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE) {
                    Display.destroy();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex2i(100, 100);
            glVertex2i(mouseX, hy - mouseY - 1);
            glEnd();
            Display.update();
            Display.sync(250);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }
}
```

Looking at this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2i(100, 100);
glVertex2i(mouseX, hy - mouseY - 1);
glEnd();
Display.update();
Display.sync(250);
```

it shows that I am using a simple co-ordinate for the first point of the line, but the second point of the line is being used by my mouse co-ordinates. When I move my mouse around, instead of it being one single ling following my cursor, it creates many lines which don't go away. Is there any way to get rid of the already painted lines?

Thanks in advance. Much appreciated.

Comment: You have a loop that is drawing each successive line but you do not clear the window before hand, so the lines stack up.  Inside your loop you should do a clear first, then only one line would be visible.

Comment: How do I clear? I tried using the glClear() method but that did not seem to work.

Comment: You need to setup the clear by defining the color with glClearColor(0f,0f,0f,0f)  (black) , glClearDepth(1.0f), glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST), glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL).  Then to clear you use glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT).